# Resistive force sensor: some basic questions about its functionality

Tags: electrical-engineering, pressure, sensors

I want to know what the [circular force sensor](http://tienda.bricogeek.com/sensores/403-sensor-de-fuerza-resistivo-circular.html) outputs when it is connected to the breadboard (with resistor). Does it output force measured in grams? When I slightly touch the sensor with a finger, the output value varies around 500-600.

Another question: Do I need to somehow calibrate the output values in order to use them for other measurements?

Comment: It's just a variable resistance. I doubt that it is calibrated at all.

Comment: 500-600 Ohms? 500-600 Volts? 500-600 llamas?  Units are important.

Comment: Units! units! units!

Answer (score 1):

There is a link to the company's [integration guide](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/Pressure/fsrguide.pdf) on the page you linked which is very explanatory.

These sensors show a decrease in resistance with increasing applied force.  I have no idea what you mean by "connected to the breadboard (with resistor)", but the most simple way to read this device would be to connect it to a [multimeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimeter) set to read resistance.  Once you know the resistance you can calculate the approximate force from the curve on page 5 of the [integration guide](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/Pressure/fsrguide.pdf) (shown below).

So, if you are reading 500 Ohms of resistance across the force sensor, then the approximate mass on the sensor (force $\neq$ mass, argh) is 4 kg.  In order to get a more accurate measurement though, you will need to calibrate the sensor with a range of known masses since every sensor produced by the company will be slightly different.

[image]